# Group List of Dictionaries by a Dictionary-key (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

I have a List of Dictionaries of type `<String, String>`. Dictionaries have the keys Revenue and Month.

A typical entry could be: Revenue = "10.080", Month = "1/2011"

I would like to get the revenue totals for each month, so I tried:

```
List<decimal> monthsTotals = data.Select(d => Convert.ToDecimal(d["Revenue"]))
    .GroupBy(d => d["Month"]).ToList<decimal>();
```

This does not work. The expression `d["Month"])` is underlined.

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'decimal'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<decimal> monthsTotals = data
  .GroupBy(d => d["Month"])
  .Select(d => d.Sum( r => Convert.ToDecimal(r["Revenue"])))
  .ToList<decimal>();
```

Answer (score 6):

The result of your `Select` is *just* the revenue. You're losing all the rest of that information. I suspect you want:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> revenueByMonth =
    data.GroupBy(d => d["Month"], d => decimal.Parse(d["Revenue"]))
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Sum());
```

The first step creates an `IGrouping<string, decimal>` - i.e. for each month, a sequence of revenue values.

The second step converts this into a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` by taking the group key (the month) as the dictionary key, and the sum of the group values as the dictionary value.

Comment: Yes, you are right, creating some kind of dictionary would have been my next step.

Comment: @Jan-FrederikCarl: Well in particular, creating a `List<decimal>` doesn't give you any useful information as far as I can see... what would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Turn those dictionaries into something useful.

```
public class RevenueData
{
   public decimal Revenue {get;set;}
   public string Month {get;set;}
}

List<RevenueData> result = data
  .Select(d => new RevenueData()
    { Revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(d["Revenue"]), Month = d["Month"] })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
  .Select(g => new RevenueData()
    { Revenue = g.Sum(x => x.Revenue), Month = g.Key })
  .ToList();
```